# Вставка элемента на n позицию в однонаправленом списке(list)

Tags: c++, списки, insert, односвязный-список

Сделал список,нужна возможность вставки на n позицию,у меня реализован сам список и итератор,реализованы функции ввода списка,сравнения двух списков.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct ListMem
{
    int listvalue;
    ListMem* next = 0;
};
class List;
class Iterator
{
  public:
    void setValue(int a);
    void next();
    int value();
    bool equal(Iterator& other);
  private:
    ListMem* item = 0;
    friend class List;
};
class List
{
  public:
    void push(int a);
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
  private:
    ListMem* cur = 0;
    ListMem* head = 0;
};
```

Comment: Ну а в чем, собственно, проблема? Проходите по списку до нужного места, перебрасываете указатели... Набросайте свой вариант, обсудим :)

Comment: @Tokiwartoot  А как функция вставки объявлена?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `insert` может быть, к примеру, определена следующим образом, как это показано в демонстрационной программе ниже

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListMem
{
    int listvalue;
    ListMem* next = 0;
};

class List;
class Iterator
{
  public:
    void setValue(int a);
    void next();
    int value();
    bool equal(Iterator& other);
  private:
    ListMem* item = 0;
    friend class List;
};


class List
{
  public:
    void push(int a);
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
    bool insert( int a, size_t n = 0 );
  private:
    ListMem* cur = 0;
    ListMem* head = 0;
};

void List::push( int a )
{
    head = new ListMem { a, head };
}

bool List::insert( int a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n == 0 )
    {
        push( a );
    }
    else
    {
        ListMem **current = &head;

        while ( *current != nullptr && --n ) current = &( *current )->next;

        if ( n == 0 )
        {
            ListMem *next = new ListMem { a, ( *current )->next };
            ( *current )-> next = next;
        }
    }

    return n == 0;
}

;int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;
    List list;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) list.insert( i, i );

    return 0;
}
```